# xdebug, php on remote server, netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have my 1and1 hosted web site.  I've got server-side php I need to debug.
All I've found mentions running/installing xdebug when you have a *local* web server
with php and mysql on a *local* web server.

However, I'm using the remote web server hosted at 1and1 hosting.
I'm using and loving netbeans, wow great IDE.

Anyways, how (if it's even possible) can I install then use the xdebug 
debugger to debug my php code running at 1and1 from within Netbeans?

I'm wondering if it is my hosting company (1and1) that has to have xdebug installed.
I'm running the latest version of Netbeans but when I press the debug button on
the toolbar I see an error message popup that says

"There is no connection from xdebug detected within 40 seconds.  The reasons could be that **xdebug is neither installed nor properly configured.** Be sure that your php.ini file contains these entries:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on  
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp  
xdebug.remote_host=localhost (or hostname)  
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

So I searched my harddisk, and despite having installed the full Netbeans
IDE, I have no php.ini file.

So can I make xdebug work remotely, ie. can I debug my php code as it runs on the
remote 1and1 web server, using Netbeans and xdebug?

I've only been using Netbeans for 2 days and for all I know, xdebug is not even a part
of Netbeans.  Reason I say that is, I can 'run' my php remotely just fine -- it executes on the remote 1and1 web server when I push 'run' inside Netbeans -- and then the client side output on my local machine is correct.  But I cannot step into the code with xdebug by pressing the 'Debug' button on the Netbeans toolbar -- is it possible xdebug did not get installed correctly with Netbeans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xdebug should be installed inside the php folder and of course the php folder is located on the server where php is installed... at your hosting provider.

I would not expect an hosting provider to install xDebug as it seems to me it would be a huge security hole.

xDebug is not part of Netbeans and it is not part of PHP by default.

Now, looking at things on a more positive viewpoint, if you are going to develop PHP, you NEED a local server. It's very unprofessional to develop code directly on the live server.

Grab a copy of xampp and install it on your computer. Grab a copy of xdebug and install it following the instructions. Restart Apache. There, now you have a testing server.

Once you have a complete set-up on your computer, copy your PHP application's folder inside the "htdoc" folder.

NOW, and only now, should you consider developing in PHP. Develop locally, on your own testing server, xdebug will work whenever you start a debugging session from inside Netbeans.

When everything works, upload your files on your hosted space.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and it was e-z to install and get running xampp.  For xdebug it admonishes that getting Netbeans working with xdebug correctly, you might get grief if the versions of PHP, Apache are not 'in sync' with xdebug -- any sage wisdom on aligning xdebug and the versions of PHP and Apache I got in my xampp install?

Comment: Ah, wisdom. ;) Go to http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php and paste the content of your phpinfo() and it will give you the version of xdebug you need. (create phpinfo file and call it through localhost)

Comment: Thanks, I created a php_info.php file with a call to phpinfo() and then ran it -- I looked at all the output it generated and thought "surely they aren't going to parse all that" and I bailed on pasting that stuff in -- instead I looked at my install notes after doing my xampp 1.7.4 install and found out which version of PHP I had and used that to choose the right xdebug DLL from xdebug.org.

Comment: I made a php file to call phpinfo(), I thought "surely they aren't going to parse all that", I looked at my xampp 1.7.2 install notes, got my PHP version from it and downloaded the right xdebug DLL from xdebug.org. But in reading http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html#installAndEnableXDebug - I found out the xdebug DLL came with xampp. So I did the steps at the above link to modify php.ini to get Xdebug working, restarted my web server and can now debug PHP code on my new localhost XAMPP web server. I feel normal again, now I can write some code.  THANKS!

Comment: Well, whatever works. But you're wrong. Of course they parse "all that". It takes about half a second and one regex. no biggie.

Comment: I got Xdebug and Netbeans to cha on Windows exactly once; after a week of untold of grief, the old :9000 listen bug ultimately propelling me to FirePHP, a Firebug extension which imo ranks between space flight and fire on the list of nifty human inventions. Especially makes server-client middleware (ajax,json,rest,etc) easy peasy. Bunch of projects to integrate them are in progess, albeit all are slow-moving. Their respective functionality complements so well I don't notice the absence of formal integration (though I'm sure I'll be questioning how I managed without it once it ships!)

Comment: FYI xampp has xdebug downloaded by default, all you need to do is uncomment some lines in php.ini to enable it